# Node.js C++ addon global variable scope

Tags: c++, node.js, variables, scope

I would appreciate if anyone could elaborate about the variable scopes in c++ addons of node js. For example, I have initialized some global variables in the addon (c++ file) like "int size" or something like this. so when I call the function in that addon it doesn't reinitialize the value. in fact if I assign something in some function "size = 27" and then after some time I call another function of that addon it will see size equal to 27. so when is addon stack deallocated and global variables reinitialized in C++ Addons?

Thanks,

Comment: So you set a value `size` to `27` and then later read the value and it is `27`. How is that a problem and not exactly what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Global variables are not allocated on the stack. The space to store them is allocated separately on library load and deallocated on library unload (or process termination). And your addon does not have any stack at all, when addon function is called it will use nodejs main thread stack.

Comment: In my understanding when I call addon's function the addon is reinitialized. so when function terminates whole addon code is 'disappeared. So my question: Does node kind of cache addon's variables and their values? or are addons reinitialized on every function call?